# Openlayers 3 mass feature update: update existing features or trash source and recreate from scratch?

Tags: javascript, performance, garbage-collection, openlayers-3

I want to build a Openlayers 3 map, wrapped in a React Component, that can track a fleet of vehicles in real-time. Consequently, the vehicle positions are being updated every second.

Concerned about the performance implications of continuiously mutating objects or trash/replacing them.

Do I built code infrastructure to go through and update each and every feature every update (at least once a second)

**or**

do I just throw out the source of the fleet layer and rebuild the source and features with every real-time data update?

The below link has been the most relevant I have found so far. Seeking out further advice or if someone has more specific experience of this tradeoff with Openlayers 3

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/304574/does-immutability-hurt-performance-in-javascript

Comment: Whats the type of "fleet layer"? Is it WMS or WFS layer?

Comment: It is a vector layer. Updated every few seconds.

Comment: 2nd approach seems more relevant(valid) one as pointed out in the link. Since for Vector layers rendering is done from Openlayers if more number of features(in this case vehicles)
are present more processing is done in browser which might make application slow(IE).
One optimization : Convert "fleet layer" to TileWMS instead of Vector layer so creation of features is done in Geoserver (if using geoserver to get real time data) and hence less 
processing from openlayers by utilizing server side resources.